# How to work with auto_page_break() in FPDF python and how to avoid recursive error without increasing the recursion limit

Tags: python, recursion, fpdf

I'm seeking your assistance here on two issues on FPDF with python.

1. setting auto_page_break() in FPDF
   I've written a code for PDF invoice generation using FPDF with python. I have set the
   auto_page_break as in my code below but its not working.
2. Recursion Error.
   I'm getting the recursion error when I increase the number or rows of the table details. Is
   there a way the code can be written without increasing the recursion limit above 1000.

Lastly, I'm still on the basic learning stage and kindly don't crucify on my coding errors. Whatever I've presented here could be the worst but it is my best at this stage of my learning curve. Just assist me where possible.

```py
class PDF(FPDF):
    def header(self):
        def header1(self):
            #logo
            #self.image() # x,y coordinates and height
            # font
            self.set_font('times', 'B',20)
            #font Color
            self.set_text_color(10,0,165)
            # padding
            self.cell(25)
            # title
            self.cell(25, 6, 'COMPANY NAME', border=False, ln=0, align='L')
            self.cell(105)
            self.cell(25, 4, 'INVOICE', border=False, ln=1, align='L')
            self.ln(3)

        header1(self)
        def header2(self):
            self.set_font('times', '', 12)
            self.cell(25, 6, '', border=False, ln=0, align='L')
            self.cell(30, 6, 'Address line 2', border=False, ln=0, align='L')
            self.cell(71)
            self.cell(30, 6, 'Date', border=False, ln=0, align='R')
            self.cell(1)
            self.cell(30, 6, " ", border=True, ln=1, align='L')
            self.cell(25, 6, " ", border=False, ln=0, align='L')
            self.cell(30, 6, 'Address line 2', border=False, ln=0, align='L')
            self.cell(71)
            self.cell(30, 6, 'Invoice No.', border=False, ln=0, align='R')
            self.cell(1)
            self.cell(30, 6, " ", border=True, ln=1, align='L')
            self.cell(25, 6, '', border=False, ln=0, align='L')
            self.cell(30, 6, 'www.company.com', border=False, ln=0, align='L')
            self.cell(71)
            self.cell(30, 6, 'Customer ID', border=False, ln=0, align='R')
            self.cell(1)
            self.cell(30, 6, " ", border=True, ln=1, align='L')
            # linebreak
        header2(self)
        self.ln(5)
        def bill_to(self):
            self.set_font('times', 'B', 14)
            self.set_fill_color(169, 169, 150)
            self.set_text_color(100,10,0)
            self.cell(80, 6, 'BILL TO', border=False, ln=1, align='L',fill=1) # 1st line
            self.ln(2)
            def customer_address(self):
                self.set_font('times', '', 12)
                self.set_fill_color(0, 0, 0)
                self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
                for i in range(1,5):
                    self.cell(80, 6, 'Address Line', border=False, ln=1, align='L') # 2nd line
                self.set_line_width(0.00)
            customer_address(self)
        bill_to(self)
        self.ln(2)
        # page body
        def body_header(self):
            # Set Font color, Fill Color and text color
            self.set_font('times', 'B', 14)
            self.set_fill_color(169, 169, 150)
            self.set_text_color(100, 10, 0)
            # Set column cells
            self.cell(15,10,'NO',ln=0,align='C',fill=1), self.cell(1)
            self.cell(100,10,'Item Description',ln=0,align='C',fill=1), self.cell(1)
            self.cell(25,10,'Price',ln=0,align='C',fill=1),self.cell(1)
            self.cell(20,10,'Qty',ln=0,align='C',fill=1),self.cell(1)
            self.cell(25,10,'Total',ln=1,align='C',fill=1)

        body_header(self)
        def body_details(self):
            # Set Font color, Fill Color and text color
            self.set_font('times', '', 12), self.set_fill_color(178, 190, 181),self.set_text_color(0, 10, 0)

            # Setting Details Table area for input variables

            for i in range(1,13): # Just for testing if the details will spill over to the next page after page brake
                self.ln(1.3)
                self.cell(15, 8, '', ln=0, align='C', fill=1), self.cell(1)
                self.cell(100, 8, '', ln=0, align='C', fill=1), self.cell(1)
                self.cell(25, 8, '', ln=0, align='C', fill=1), self.cell(1)
                self.cell(20, 8, '', ln=0, align='C', fill=1), self.cell(1)
                self.cell(25, 8, '', ln=1, align='C', fill=1)
            self.ln(7)

            self.set_font('times', 'B', 14)
            self.cell(25, 5, 'Payment Details', ln=1, align='L', fill=0)
            self.set_font('times', '', 12)
            self.cell(25, 5, 'Bank Name:   XYZ', ln=0, align='L', fill=0)
            self.cell(104)
            self.cell(25, 5, 'Sub Total', ln=0, align='R', fill=0)
            self.cell(10)
            self.cell(25, 5, '', ln=1, align='C', fill=0,border=1) # Variable
            self.cell(25, 5, 'Bank Account No:   XYZ', ln=0, align='L', fill=0)
            self.cell(105)
            self.cell(25, 5, 'Vat Rate', ln=0, align='R', fill=0)
            self.cell(9)
            self.cell(25, 5, '', ln=1, align='C', fill=0, border=1)  # Variable
            self.cell(25, 5, 'Bank Branch:   XYZ', ln=0, align='L', fill=0)
            self.cell(105)
            self.cell(25, 5, 'Vat Amount', ln=0, align='R', fill=0)
            self.cell(9)
            self.cell(25, 5, '', ln=1, align='C', fill=0, border=1)  # Variable
            self.cell(25, 5, 'Bank Swift Code:   XYZ', ln=0, align='L', fill=0)
            self.set_font('times', 'B', 14)
            self.cell(105)
            self.cell(25, 5, 'Total Amount', ln=0, align='R', fill=0)
            self.cell(9)
            self.cell(25, 5, '', ln=1, align='C', fill=0, border=1)  # Variable
            self.cell(25, 5, 'Bank Sort Code:   XYZ', ln=1, align='L', fill=0)

        body_details(self)
    # Page footer
    def footer(self):
        # set position of the footer
        self.set_y(-28)

        def terms_conditions(self):

            def terms_header(self):
                self.ln(4)
                self.set_font('times', 'B', 15) # font
                self.cell(40, 5, 'Terms & Conditions', ln=0)
                self.cell(105)
                self.cell(40, 5, '---------------------', ln=1,border=2)
            terms_header(self)

            def terms_body(self):
                self.set_font('times', '', 13) # font
                self.cell(40, 5, 'Payment based on', ln=0)
                self.cell(30, 5, '', ln=1) # variables
                self.cell(40, 5, 'From date of invoice as above', ln=0)
                self.cell(107)

                def signatures(self):
                    #self.set_font('times', 'B', 13)
                    self.cell(40, 5, 'Authorised Sign', ln=1)
                signatures(self)

            terms_body(self)
        terms_conditions(self)
        # page number
        self.cell(0,10, f'Page{self.page_no()}/{{nb}}', align='C') # nb returns number of pages of the document


# create FPDF Object

pdf = PDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter')

# set Margins

pdf.set_margins(15,19,10)

# get total page numbers
pdf.alias_nb_pages()

# Create Auto_Page Break method

pdf.set_auto_page_break(auto=True, margin=20),

# Add a page
pdf.add_page()

pdf.output("myfile.pdf")
```

Comment: Please format the code. Also please read some tutorials about python programming, there are many issues with your code.

Comment: @quamrana thanks alot for editing. I copied  the code and pasted ,I din't understand why some parts were left out.